# DebugBreak for iPad

Tags: assembly, arm, ipad, debugbreak

I want to make DebugBreak for iPad and found that asm{trap} should work, but there is a problem: if I use asm{trap} I have error: asm blocks not enabled, use `-fasm-blocks'. If I enable -fasm-blocks I have another error: -fasm-blocks option not supported for ARM.

Do you know another way to implement DebugBreak or to make asm code compile on the iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and work-around this problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTRAP